# Disable dictation function on Android keyboard

Tags: android, dictation

Is it possible to disable the dictation feature/button via the SDK per textview or per app?

Comment: Does [this give you any hints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6709051/1270789)?

Comment: I guess you dont want to show hint above keyboard.